# Can a function mapping any set to its lower upper bound be bijective?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I wonder whether a function mapping any **bounded** set of reals A to a number that is set's least upper bound be both surjective and injective? Is it the same with function mapping to set's greatest lower bound?

My thinking is that it can not be injective, as two different sets could potentially have the same supremum. It can not be surjective either as the set $\mathbb{R}$ is not covered.

Not sure if my simple thinking is correct?

Comment: This seems like a function definition, not just a property of an unknown function, unless you consider different domains within the set of non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I agree the function is not injective, but it is surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will surely be surjective: for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, the singleton $\{r\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ has $r$ as supremum (and also infimum).

It is also correct that it is not injective. Both $[-1,0]$ and $[-2,0]$ have the same supremum.

The same thing happens for the "lower bound" function, it will be surjective and not inective.